# How to use fzero() to solve polynomial equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, solver, polynomial-math, polynomial-approximations

I would like to solve the following polynomial numerically for `r`:

I am trying to use `fzero()` as follows:

```
r = (5/(r^2*9))- ((2)/(9*(6-r)^2))
x0 = 10; % some initial point
x = fzero(r,x0)
```

How can this be done with `fzero()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Input variable and function name should be different
- Just change the function name to `pol`
- To use `fzero` the function `pol` have to be a **function handle**
  defined via `@`

```
pol =@(r) (5/(r^2*9))- ((2)/(9*(6-r)^2))
x0 = 10; % some initial point
x = fzero(pol,x0)
```

solution

```
x =  3.6754
```

Comment: Though it is good practice to use a different name for the function handle and for the anonymous variable (and I highly recommend doing this), it is not necessary. But you were missing the `@` indicating that `r =` is a function handle; and you were missing a `(r)` just after the @ to say that you have an **anonymous** function handle and that `r` should be considered as an input *variable*. i.e. `r = @(r)  (5/(r^2*9))- ((2)/(9*(6-r)^2))` would have worked but it is confusing to use `r` here twice, just as @Adam explained

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that, the first argument in `fzero()` should be "*a function handle, inline function, or string containing the name of the function to evaluate*", but yours is just an expression, which is not valid.

Besides the approach by [@Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59332873/12158757) (using function handle), another way is to use anonymous function, i.e.,

```
 x = fzero(@(r) (5/(r^2*9))- ((2)/(9*(6-r)^2)) ,x0)
```

where

```
@(r) (5/(r^2*9))- ((2)/(9*(6-r)^2))
```

is the anonymous function with respect to argument `r`.

You will get the same result that `x =  3.6754`.

Comment: Makes sense. I have been using fsolve, but I wanted the fzero approach.